# How many BNB coins do I need for a Blockchain Project? It is a simple decentralized drive and I have around 0.0448 BNB in my MetaMask account

Tags: blockchain, solidity, project, decentralized-applications, web3-react

I am new to this domain and have no idea how many transaction fees will be needed. They are simple operations like giving access of an image to a user and uploading images.

I need to show this project to my professor today!

Answer (score 0):

The gas fees for a transaction in native token (BNB on Binance Smart Chain, ETH on Ethereum, MATIC on Polygon, ...) are calculated using the following formula:

*native token fee amount = gas units * gas price*

---

The amount of *gas units* for executing the transaction **depends on the complexity of the code that you're executing**. There's a base amount of 21 thousand gas units for sending a transaction, plus whatever amount the contract consumes. Usually, contract execution consumes **from thousands to tens of thousands** of gas units.

*Gas price* is market driven. According to [BSCScan](https://bscscan.com/gastracker), the gas price right now is 3 Gwei ( = 3,000,000,000 wei), but it does change overtime depending on the network usage.

Given the example numbers, a transaction costing *21,000 gas units* times *3 Gwei gas price* results in the overall cost of 63,000 Gwei == 0.000063 BNB.

If the cost of executing the contract function is *50,000 gas units*, and the *gas price is still 3 Gwei*, then the overall cost is 150,000 Gwei == 0.00015 BNB.